# "Seq[Class[_ <: akka.actor.Actor]] is abstract but not sealed" error upon compilation

Tags: scala

I'm trying to create a list of error listener classes that are instantiated at a later time.

The expression in question is:

```
import configs.syntax._
import akka.actor.Actor

private val errorListeners = applicationConfig
    .get[Seq[Class[_ <: Actor]]]("connectors.event-listeners")
    .valueOrElse(Seq.empty)
```

Which causes the following error upon compilation:

```
EventListenerProvider.scala:12:33: Seq[Class[_ <: akka.actor.Actor]] is abstract but not sealed
[error]     .get[Seq[Class[_ <: Actor]]]("connectors.event-listeners")
```

Comment: Did I understand it correctly that it is a [Config](https://lightbend.github.io/config/latest/api/com/typesafe/config/Config.html) used with [kxbmap/configs](https://github.com/kxbmap/configs)? In this case, I don't see where in [this list](https://github.com/kxbmap/configs#supported-types) it says anything about being able to `get` something like `Class[_ <: Actor]`?

Comment: That is correct.  I've been able to do things like `.get[FiniteDuration](...)` before, so I thought I might be able to do this as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [list](https://github.com/kxbmap/configs#supported-types) explicitly enumerates all the types that are supported by `get`. There is no reason whatsoever to expect that a library that provides some thin layer of syntactic sugar for reading strings using the `Config` library would all of the sudden return instances of type `Class[_]`. It can do some basic transformation of stringly-typed config values into `String`s, `Int`s, `List`s, and some simple `case`-classes, but it is not meant as a generic way to deserialize arbitrary classes from strings. I assume that the error message comes from a macro that attempts to interpret `Class` as a sealed trait, but then fails, because it is `abstract` but not `sealed`.

Don't expect too much from the library. It's for reading strings, not for dealing with `ClassLoader`s. Read the names of classes as list of strings, then map it using `Class.forName` or something like that.